# How to combine fulltext search with other optinals matches in MongoDb?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, full-text-search, aggregate

I try to query my collection with only one query and 3 potentials search method:

- fulltext search
- classic search
- search regex

This 3 matches can be executed at the same time or just one of them.
The fulltext search is the first stage pipeline as we know. Does this fulltext search can be optional in my aggregate? Because if my default value of search is "", my query returns any data. And I need data to perform my other optionals matches.
Here is my Laravel 8 controller :

```php
Product::raw(function ($collection) use($filters, $fullText, $likeKey, $likeValue){
                                    return $collection->aggregate([
                                        [        
                                            '$match' =>
                                            [
                                                '$text' =>['$search' => $fullText],
                                                                        
                                            ],
                                            
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            '$match' => $filters
                                        ],
                                        [   
                                           '$match' => 
                                                [
                                                    $likeKey => 
                                                        [
                                                            '$regex' => $likeValue,
                                                            '$options' => "i"
                                                        ]
                                                ]
                                        ],
                                      
                                        [
                                            '$addFields' => 
                                                [
                                                    'avgReviews' => ['$avg' => '$reviews.ranking'],
                                                    'price' => ['$min' => '$variants.price'],
                                                    'equipmentsList' =>  [
                                                        '$reduce' => [
                                                            'input' => '$equipments.list.list',
                                                            'initialValue' => [],
                                                            'in' => 
                                                                [
                                                                    '$concatArrays' => [
                                                                        '$$value',
                                                                        '$$this'
                                                                    ]
                                                                ]           
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                ],
                                        ]                           
                                    ]);
                                })
                    ->when($operations, function($products) use ($operations){
                        foreach($operations as $key => $operation){                            
                            return $products
                                ->where($operation[0],$operation[1],$operation[2]);
                        }
                    })
                    ->forPage($page,$limit)
                    ->sortBy($sortBy, SORT_REGULAR, $order == 'desc')
                    ->values();
```

`$filters` is an array and works fine when it's the only one match. But if I want to use `$filters` without `$text`, it returns any data. And with the third match, nothing works. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You need to construct the query conditionally based on the available criteria instead of always having all of the fragments in it.

Comment: Thank you, you re right. I found the solution yesterday building my arrays before my return in if conditions :)